# Splunk SearchResultStream iteration hangs when there are no results

Tags: c#, .net, splunk

Found an issue with Splunk SDK for C# v2.2.3.

When I submit a search that doesn't return any result, execution of my code hangs on enumerating results from SearchResultStream:

```
using (SearchResultStream stream = await _service.SearchOneShotAsync(searchCommand, 0, new JobArgs { EarliestTime = earliestTime, LatestTime = latestTime }))
{
    foreach (var searchresult in stream)
    {
        result.add(searchresult);
    }
}
```

Also tried to use enumerator directly, but it doesn't help, program hangs on `enumerator.MoveNext()`:

```
using (SearchResultStream stream = await _service.SearchOneShotAsync(searchCommand, 0, new JobArgs { EarliestTime = earliestTime, LatestTime = latestTime }))
{
    var enumerator = stream.GetEnumerator();
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        result.Add(enumerator.Current);
    }
}
```

Has anybody faced with the same problem? Are there any workaround?
We use Splunk Enterprise version 6.3.3.

Comment: Well, looks that downgrading Splunk.Client to version 2.2.2 solves the problem.